# How do i implement Logic to Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

So I have an assignment to build a web interface for a smart sensor, 
I've already written the python code to read the data from the sensor and write it into sqlite3, control the sensor etc.

I've built the HTML, CSS template and implemented it into Django.

My goal is to run the sensor reading script pararel to the Django interface on the same server, so the server will do all the communication with the sensor and the user will be able to read and configure the sensor from the web interface. (Same logic as modern routers - control and configure from a web interface)

Q: Where do I put my sensor_ctl.py script in my Django project and how I make it to run independent on the server. (To read sensor data 24/7)
Q: Where in my Django project I use my classes and method from  sensor_ctl.py to write/read data to my djangos database instead of the local sqlite3 database (That I've used to test sensor_ctl.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your code in app/appname/management/commands folder. Use Official guide for **management commands**. Then you will be able to use your custom command like this:
./manage getsensorinfo
So when you will have this command registered, you can just  put in in cron and it will be executed every minute.
Secondly you need to rewrite your code to use **django ORM** models like this:
Stat.objects.create(temp1=60,temp2=70) instead of INSERT into....

Comment: Thank you! management commands is the term I was looking for.